# Why Mathematica cannot tell if Sqrt[Abs[u0^2 + v0^2/b^2]] is positive?

Tags: inequalities

In the code below I was careful to declare all variables as real and to use Refine. Still, Mathematica cannot tell that a sum of squares is a positive number. What am I missing?

Thanks to DumpsterDoofus and Bob Hanlon for pointing out that I overlooked the possibility that c might be zero. My question becomes: Is there a way to tell Mathematica that u0, v0, and b are positive so that c must also be positive? I edited the code so as to include the statement u0 > 0, v0 > 0, b > 0 in Refine but that did not work as I expected.

Thanks for any help.

```
In[118]:= reals = b \[Element] Reals && u0 \[Element] Reals && v0 \[Element] Reals && c \[Element] Reals;

In[119]:= c = Abs[Refine[((v0/b)^2 + u0^2)^(1/2), {reals, u0 > 0, v0 > 0, b > 0}]]
Refine[u0 \[Element] Reals, reals]
Refine[v0 \[Element] Reals, reals]
Refine[b \[Element] Reals, reals]
Refine[c \[Element] Reals, reals]
Refine[Simplify[c > 0], reals]
Refine[Simplify[c^2 > 0], reals]

Out[119]= Sqrt[Abs[u0^2 + v0^2/b^2]]
Out[120]= True
Out[121]= True
Out[122]= True
Out[123]= True
Out[124]= Sqrt[u0^2 + v0^2/b^2] > 0
Out[125]= u0^2 + v0^2/b^2 > 0
```

Comment: It's not giving what you expect because what you're saying is not correct (take a look at your math again). I'll post a brief explanation in a minute.

Answer (score 4):

Because it could be zero.

```
reals = Element[{b, u0, v0, c}, Reals];

c = ((v0/b)^2 + u0^2)^(1/2);

Simplify[#, reals] & /@
 {c > 0, c^2 > 0,
  c >= 0, c^2 >= 0}
```

> {Sqrt[u0^2 + v0^2/b^2] > 0,     b^2*u0^2 + v0^2 > 0, True, True}

Answer (score 4):

The statement
$$\sqrt{u_0^2+v_0^2/b^2}>0\text{ when } u_0,v_0,b\in\mathbb{R}$$
is false, and I think that's what's confusing you. However, it's true when $>$ is replaced by $\geq$.

In code:

```
Simplify[c >= 0, reals]
(*True*)
```